# apex tag to show all the children

Tags: apex, html

I'm working on a visual force page to look like almost exactly as a default sales-force page, now my question is: 
is there an apex tag to bring all the children records like we have in the default salesforce page or should I implement a table from scratch. something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy! The apex tag you need is apex:relatedList.

For its usage, refer: http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_relatedList.htm

Also, to check for all the tags available in Visualforce page, you can refer to the Visualforce pdf: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/salesforce_pages_developers_guide.pdf